# Method returns negative value

Tags: java, if-statement, double, false-positive

I am trying to create a method that checks if an input is a double that is greater than zero. Checking if it is indeed a double is working fine with my code, but, even though when entering negatives its prompts to reenter the value, in the end, after entering a positive value it returns the negative entered earlier

```
 public static double isValid(double v){
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    if (scan.hasNextDouble()){
     v = scan.nextDouble();
     if (v<=0) {
        System.out.println("You have to use a positive number");
        isValid(v);
     }
     else {
        return v;
     }
  }
  else {
     System.out.println("Thats not how it works");
     isValid(v);
  }
  return v;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to return the result of your recursive calls:

```
return isValid(v);
```

It's returning the last invalid value because after returning from the recursive call, execution continues down to the return at the bottom of the method, returning `v`. At this point, `v` is the last invalid value.

Comment: Also there's no actual need for recursion

Comment: @KevinAnderson True, but that's not the question at hand. If this were code review, we could dig in a little more.

Comment: @KevinAnderson Why not?

Comment: @AlexLab This would be much simpler with a do...while loop, or something similar. Java also isn't a great language to use recursion in. If your user enters too many invalid values, your program will crash with a SO.